# aiogram || invalid

Tags: python, aiogram, syntax

Пишу бота телеграм (aiogram). До этого не стыкался с этой проблемой, все было отлично.

Вот код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton




bot = Bot(token = '')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True).add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Периметр', callback_data='per').add(InlineKeyboardButton('Площа', callback_data='plo'))


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('wxs')
```

Ошибка:

```
    async def start(message: types.Message):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: скрывать токен уже поздно: он всё равно доступен в истории правок, т.е. скомпрометирован. генерируйте новый.

Comment: да, создал нового бота, моя ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых вы выложили конфиденциальную информацию в общий доступ, и теперь любой желающий может делать с вашим ботом, что захочет(почти).

ошибка у вас не здесь `...async def start...`, а выше где вы маркапы добавляете, вы забыли добавить скобку после `add(InlineKeyboardButton('Периметр', callback_data='per'))` <- здесь

В общем вот корректный код:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, \
    InlineKeyboardButton

bot = Bot(token='')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(InlineKeyboardButton('Периметр', callback_data='per')).add(
    InlineKeyboardButton('Площа', callback_data='plo'))


@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('wxs')
```